# How to decode a csv file with long lines in tensorflow with tf.decode_csv?

Tags: csv, tensorflow

How to decode a `csv` file with long lines(e.g., with many items per line so as not realistic to list them one by one for output) with tf.TextLineReader() and tf.decode_csv?

The typical usage is:

```
reader = tf.TextLineReader()    
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)    
record_defaults = [1,1,1,1,1]    
a,b,c,d,e =  tf.decode_csv(records=value,record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim=" ")
```

When we have thousands of items in a line, it's impossible to assign them one by one as (a,b,c,d,e) above, can all the items be decoded to a list or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have 1800 columns of data. You can use this as record default:

```
record_defaults=[[1]]*1800
```

and then use

```
all_columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
```

to read them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `tf.decode_csv` returns a list, so you can simply do:

```
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
all_columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
all_columns
Out: [<tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:0' shape=() dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:1' shape=() dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:2' shape=() dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:3' shape=() dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:4' shape=() dtype=int32>
]
```

You can then evaluate it as usual:

```
sess = tf.Session() 
sess.run(all_columns)
Out: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Note that you need to pass a rank 1 `record_defaults`. If you have some problems with hanging queue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I am mixing differents dtypes in the record_defaults:

```
record_defaults = [tf.constant(.1, dtype=tf.float32) for count in range(100)] # 5 fp32 features
record_defaults.extend([tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32) for count in range(2)]) # 2 int32 features
```